# How do I fix the error in my Player Controller?

Tags: controller, settings

Here's the code I wrote for my character controller:

using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float movementSpeed = 5.0f;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

     float forwardSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Verical") * movementSpeed;
     float sideSpeed = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * movementSpeed;

     Vector3 speed = new Vector3( sideSpeed, 0, forwardSpeed );

     CharacterController cc = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

     cc.SimpleMove( speed );

 }
}
```

And when I try to move my character I can't move and I get this error:

UnityException: Input Axis Vertical is not setup. To change the imput setting use: Edit -> Project Settings -> Input FirstPersonController.Update () (at Assets/Script/FirstPersonController.cs:16)

Can you help me fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Input Axis vertical is not setup.

might not help you now.
hopefully will help someone in the future.

i had this problem. turned out to be easy fix when i found it. i did not type the word vertical the same in my code.

one had a cap V the other non caps v. such a basic mistake lol.